# Vue + Spring Boot: resolving CORS errors and/or using HTTP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, http, https

I made a website with the help of Vue 2 framework and a Java server using the Spring Boot framework to better understand the workflow for submitting forms in Spring Boot:

Client (website with address `localhost:8080`):

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
    <div>
        <h3>
            MyForm
        </h3>
        <div>
            <span>Name</span>
            <input v-model="userdata.name" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Address</span>
            <input v-model="userdata.address" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button @click="submit()">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
        return {
          userdata: {
            name: "",
            address: ""
          }
        }
    },
    methods: {
      async submit() {
        const resp = await this.$axios.post("https://localhost:8085/api/v1/form", 
        this.userdata);
        console.log(resp);
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Server at `localhost:8085`:

`SampleRequestHandler.java`:

```
package com.example.sample;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080", maxAge = 1800)
@RequestMapping("")
@RestController
public class SampleRequestHandler {
    public SampleRequestHandler() {
        //...
    }

    // @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/form")
    public JSONObject submitForm(@RequestBody JSONObject form) {
        form.put("processed", true);
        return form;
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1
server.port=8085
```

The client at `localhost:8080` will submit the form to `localhost:8085`; the server will then intercept this request via the `submitForm()` method, process the form and return a response.

But when I ran both client and server, and tried to submit the form through the client, I have been getting errors such as:

1. `POST https://localhost:8085/api/v1/form net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when making axios request to https URL. Shows up in server as `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens`
2. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8085/api/v1/form' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` when explicitly making request to http URL.
3. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8085/api/v1/form' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes` when simply calling the localhost URL.

Since I knew that HTTPS has some other requirements, I wanted to use HTTP for both client and server to avoid CORS issues. Can this be done in Spring Boot? Is there another way to circumvent the CORS issues?

Answer (score 0):

For error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

Maybe, you coded wrong here.

```
methods: {
      async submit() {
        // SHOULD BE http://localhost:8085/api/v1/form NOT https://localhost:8085/api/v1/form
        const resp = await this.$axios.post("https://localhost:8085/api/v1/form", 
        this.userdata);
        console.log(resp);
      }
    }
```